# Una duda sobre los puertos en node.js

Tags: nodejs

```
const http = require('node:http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log('request received');
    res.end('hola mundo'); 
})

server.listen(0, () => {
    console.log(`server listening on port http://localhost:${server.address().port}` );
} )
```

Yo tengo este codigo, al ir a la terminal de VS Code, este ejecuta en un puerto.

Digamos en mi primer ejecucion este abre desde el puerto 5...38

Ahora, cierro el servidor(CTRL + C en terminal).

Vuelvo a abrir y me abre el puerto 5...39

Cierro y vuelvo a abrir y es el piuerto 5...42

Mi duda es, ven que el puerto empezo en 38 y ahora llego a 42? que el numero que asciende es el ultimo hasta que llegue a 0 de nuevo y aumenta el anteultimo digito.

Esto que significa? o sea, los puertos anteriores quedaron ocupados o tienen algo que impide que se vuelvan a usar o estoy cerrando mal los puertos al usar CTRL + C que es con el que detengo el servidor?

Tengo dudas de si esto esta afectando mis puertos o que, tengo la version de node de la pagina oficial (20.11.0 LTS).
El CTRL + C es por defecto en terminal en VS Code.

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo estás utilizando? La documentación indica que la asignación del puerto depende del SO.

Comment: Estoy usando Windows. No tengo mucha idea del tema de puertos, recien arranco con node

Comment: Y porqué razón querrías levantar tu servidor pasando como parámetro del puerto un cero?

Comment: Ahora si la duda es sobre el porqué pasa esto, basta leer la [documentación](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serverlistenport-host-backlog-callback), donde dice: *If port is __omitted or is 0__, the operating system will assign an arbitrary unused port, which can be retrieved by using server.address().port...*

Comment: **los puertos anteriores quedaron ocupados?** No, a menos que el proceso de Node quede abierto. Pero en principio, si el proceso termina correctamente, el puerto usado se libera.

Comment: Ah no, solo estoy probando como va el tema de node con puertos y servidor usando el import node:net y node:http.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los puertos no se están quedando ocupados, cuando termina el proceso node.js, se liberan.

En el `server.listen` lo más habitual es especificar un puerto concreto, para saber de antemano qué puerto va a utilizar. Si especificas `0` como puerto, el sistema te asignará uno libre arbitrariamente, como especifica en la documentación:

> If port is omitted or is 0, the operating system will assign an
> arbitrary unused port, which can be retrieved by using
> server.address().port after the 'listening' event has been emitted.

Esto quiere decir que no tiene por qué ser el mismo puerto que en una ejecución anterior, aunque se haya vuelto a quedar libre.

Por otro lado, puedes comprobar qué puertos tienes ocupados actualmente con un comando `netstat` o similar, por ejemplo en Ubuntu puedes poner:

> netstat -ltnp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      890/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1300/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1606/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1606/smbd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      890/systemd-resolve 
tcp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*                    LISTEN      2672/kdeconnectd    
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1606/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1606/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1300/cupsd
```

Y también puedes ver qué proceso está usando cada puerto (puede que necesites ser root para ver todos los procesos).